# how to get User id from auth_user table in django?

Tags: python, django

how to get User id from  `auth_user` table in django. Suppose username is availlable to me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming the user exists:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

User.objects.get(username=the_username).pk
```

Comment: Thanks Pavel. It worked par fact for me. Just not sure why you used .pk at last. I think it will fetch the id only not the tuple right?

Comment: Feel free to use `.id`, it's just a habit. What tuple?

Comment: @PavelAnossov A nice habit, since the attribute working as primary key doesn't necessarily have to be named as 'id'.

Comment: @DibyenduDutta if PavelAnossov had the correct answer, it would help if you accepted it.  Thanks!

Comment: It is suggested to use `get_user_model()` / `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` to get the User model instead of importing it directly

Answer (score 1):

User doesn't have backend so you have to use a UserManager (or BaseUserManager if you have custom User class)

```
BaseUserManager.get_by_natural_key(username)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager